# React, update DOM elements on submit on posted data without refresh

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I am playing around with React and Rails and I am working on a function to submit a post to the server, which works as intended, but then re-renders the DOM elements without refreshing the page.

I am aware I am missing a function that would get the new JSON object and map it over the DOM again but am unsure how to properly formulate this.

From my research, I would have to do a new $.ajax request on the '/posts' route, which is already set up as a JSON only render pulling all posts.

My code is below:

```
var New = React.createClass ({

handleClick(e) {

e.preventDefault();

let text = this.refs.text.value;

$.ajax({
  url: '/new',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { post: { text: text} },
  success: (post) => {
    this.handleSubmit(post);
  }
});
},
handleSubmit(post) {
console.log(post);
this.refs.text.value = ""

},

render: function() {
    return( <div>
              <div className="post-div">
                <form>
                <input className="form-control" ref='text' placeholder='Post Something' />
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>

        )
  }
})
```

and the other react file:

```
var Post = React.createClass ({

render: function() {
    return 
            <div className="text-box">
            <p className="text">{this.props.text}</p>
            <div className="text-stamps">{this.props.timestamps}</div>
            </div>;
 }
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: @alexjtark did my answer below help? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ReactJS introductory tutorial has exactly the same functionality explained in a great detail.

I'd definitely direct you to look at it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html). And [here's](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#adding-new-comments) the section that directly does what you want. POSTing a comment to the server and re-rendering it back to the client. And it also shows how to optimistically render the new comment in the UI.

Update: Here is how you can do it. The comments are the place where you will add hooks into the server call.

```
var posts = [
    {id: 1, text: "iPhone 7 release date"},
    {id: 2, text: "Samsung 7 release date"}
  ];

  var Post = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      return (<p>{this.props.text}</p>);
    }
  });

  var PostList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var response = this.props.posts.map(function(post){
        return (<Post text={post.text}></Post>);
      });
      return (<div>
        {response}
      </div>);
    }
  });

  var PostForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {newPost: ""};
    },

    handleTextChange: function(e){
      this.setState({newPost: e.target.value});
    },

    onSubmit: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var newPost = this.state.newPost.trim();
      if(!newPost) {
        return ;
      }

      this.props.onAddition(newPost);

      this.setState({newPost: ""})
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <h4>Add some post here</h4>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.newPost} onChange={this.handleTextChange}></input>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Post" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  });

  var Page = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {posts: posts};
    },
    onAddition: function(newPost) {
      console.log("Adding new: ",newPost);
      posts.push({id: Date.now(), text:newPost});

      //POST to the server here and set the state if successful
      this.setState({posts: posts});
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
      //Load from there server here
      //And keep reloading it from the server every few seconds
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <PostForm onAddition={this.onAddition}/>
          <PostList posts={this.state.posts}/>
        </div>
      );
    }
  });

  var div = document.getElementById("app");
  ReactDOM.render(<Page/>, div);
```

And here's a JSBin for this. https://jsbin.com/pokoja/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thanks for this, got playing around more with it and got it sorted. Thanks!

Comment: is it wise to keep reloading the data from server  ? can we do it in one optimized call ?

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to Kumar's answer because his solution mutates state and might be difficult for people who do not use the `getInitialState` function.

```
onAddition = (newPost) => {
const posts = [...this.state.posts]
posts.push({
  _id: Date.now,
  text: newPost.post
})

this.setState({
  posts: posts,
  postForm: {
    post: ''
  }
})}
```

In this instance, the contents of posts in state are copied (using the spread operator) and assigned to a posts constant. Then the new data is pushed into the constant, which is then set as the new state (along with the copied contents of the existing state).